# Using and transactions

Tags: c#, sql, firebird

Please let me know if the bellow code is correct. 
I mean **connection is closed and disposed** and **transaction is closed and disposed and rolled back in case of exception.**
Any other suggestions are welcome.

Thank you,
Adrya

```
using (FbConnection c = new FbConnection(m_connection))
{
    c.Open();
    using (FbTransaction trans = c.BeginTransaction())
    {
        using (FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand("DELETE_MESSAGES_QUEUE", c, trans))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("INQUEUENAME", queueName);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        using (FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand("DELETE_QUEUE", c, trans))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("INQUEUENAME", queueName);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        trans.Commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does FbTransaction rollback if an exception is thrown?

Comment: But you can just check it. Make your SP divide by zero (cause an exception) and see if transaction would get rolled back. Make SYSDBA connection from flamerobin and see in the Monitoring Tables which connections/transactions/statements are live or closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this code seems perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use a transaction scope instead, not sure of disposing a transaction rolls it back, TransactionScope does however.

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
using (var c = new FbConnection(m_connection))
{
        using (var cmd = new FbCommand("DELETE_MESSAGES_QUEUE", c))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("INQUEUENAME", queueName);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        using (var cmd = new FbCommand("DELETE_QUEUE", c))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("INQUEUENAME", queueName);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        scope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: SqlTransaction is disposed on rollback. I have no idea about FbTransaction. Using TransactionScope may or may not work depending on whether FbConnection supports it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. The [`Dispose`](https://github.com/cincuranet/FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient/blob/master/Provider/src/FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient/FirebirdClient/FbTransaction.cs#L91) method will dispose the underlying transaction and that, if transaction is still running, does the rollback ([i.e. here](https://github.com/cincuranet/FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient/blob/master/Provider/src/FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient/Client/Managed/Version10/GdsTransaction.cs#L81)).

If the exception happens on server side (or i.e. the connection is lost), then server rollbacks the transaction.